# Android Google Map draw line between current position with another fixed place

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement map on my android app where it show place on map like branch locator.

On my code it only show two marker one yellow and one green, Now How can I draw a line between two marker and also get distance between them by helping Map navigation.

Where `LatLng pp = new LatLng(23.72553, 90.41577);` my fixed place 
and

Where `LatLng gps = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());` my Current position on map

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public static final int LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE = 10;
    public static final int LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME = 5000;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if ( location != null ) {
                // Logger.d(String.format("%f, %f", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                drawMarker(location);
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
            } else {
                // Logger.d("Location is null");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps_navi);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        getCurrentLocation();

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        //Initialize Google Play Services
        int googlePlayStatus = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if ( googlePlayStatus != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(googlePlayStatus, this, -1).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            if ( mMap != null ) {
                if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Location location = null;
        if ( !(isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled) ) {
            //Snackbar.make(mMap,"Eoorrr", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
        } else {
            if ( isNetworkEnabled ) {
                if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
                location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
                location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }
        }
        if (location != null) {
            //  Log.i(String.format("getCurrentLocation(%f, %f)", location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
            drawMarker(location);
        }
    }
    private void drawMarker(Location location) {
        TextView BranchName = findViewById(R.id.nameTextView); //get the name of Branch
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.clear();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            MarkerOptions mLocationMarker = new MarkerOptions();
            MarkerOptions brLocationMarker = new MarkerOptions();
            //icons for marker
            mLocationMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            brLocationMarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
            //Current Location
            LatLng gps = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(mLocationMarker.position(gps).title("My Position"));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(gps, 16));
            //Branch Location
            LatLng pp = new LatLng(23.72553, 90.41577);
            mMap.addMarker(brLocationMarker.position(pp).title("Another Place" + CalculationByDistance(pp, gps))).showInfoWindow();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pp, 16));

        }
    }

    //Calculate distance
    public String CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        String Distance;
        int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
        double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
        double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
        double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
        double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        double valueResult = Radius * c;
        double km = valueResult / 1;
        DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
        int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
        double meter = valueResult % 1000;
        int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
        // Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec + " Meter   " + meterInDec);
        return (kmInDec + " KM " +  meterInDec  + " Meter");
    }


}
```

Here is my Map fragment

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ContactDetail" />
```

Comment: do you want to find the distance between the two locations or you want to find the routes between the two locations?

Comment: find the routes between the two locations

Comment: Related: you can open it explicitly by map-intent too. with 5-6 line code.

Comment: There are many tutorials, like [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/google-maps-directions-api-5b2e11dee9b0) or [that](https://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the functionality to show routes between the two locations you should use polylines 
[Documentation for adding ploylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial#add_a_polyline_to_draw_a_line_on_the_map)

Here is a tutorial you can refer to achieve the functionality

[Tutorial for adding polylines between two loactions](https://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points)

maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that tutorial create point on click on maps but in my question I already have two point

Comment: call these functions with your two locations

Comment: String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);

Comment: Can you edit my code and show me an example. ?I am very new with android coding bro